# Distributed ASP.Net State Service

Tags: asp.net, service, state

I'm wondering if there exist any distributed ASP.Net State Service alternative.

Session can be stored in InProc, StateService or SQL. You can also write custom storage providers. For load balancing (without any form of sticky IP) only SQL/Custom will work.

Are there any alternative ASP.Net State Services that is distributed? I'm thinking so each server can synchronize with the others.

Edit: In response to answers: I am looking for Session() storage. Distributed cache is not a problem, Velocity will do fine for distributed caching. :)

Edit2: In response to Oded: State server has the problem of single point of failure. SQL server may not be directly accessible because of the model chosen (i.e. 3-layer), it is only accessible through the middle layer.

Comment: Why is a state server or SQL not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought thats what "velocity" was going to be bringing to the table? You might want to check out [Microsoft AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) for your needs.

Edit:
Maybe I'm missing something about your post and your edit, but I'm still pretty sure AppFabric is what you need for your [`Session()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx) storage. Maybe I'm wrong, but it sure seems dead on to me.

Comment: Spot on. AppFabric seems to do exactly what I need. :)

Comment: Glad it was what you needed. For what it's worth, I had added that same link to where it says `Session()` on my edit.

Comment: Microsoft will end mainstream product support for AppFabric on April 11, 2017 and end extended product support in 2022: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/06/22/windows-server-appfabric.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [Memcache for .net](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/tips-tricks/sweet-scalability-its-memcached-for-net-001692.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725582(WS.10).aspx

I'd recommend to stay with SQL server since it will be the easiest to implement.

Make sure the classes you store in session are marked as [Serializable] or you will get runtime errors.